# Excel 2016 - How Do I Change The Border Line Color from Default Black to Another Color

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, default-settings, border

In Excel 2016, the default border line color is black. Is there a way to change the default to another color?

Answer (score 1):

You may change the color of Gridline.
Go to `File > Options > Advanced > change the Gridlien color under "Display options for this worksheet"`.

Then the default color of border line would change as it changes.
[image]

But if you want to change the default borfer line color of table, you could create **a new table style**.
Select an existing table > Design > Click the right expansion arrow > New Table Style > Choose Whole Table as the element > Check the box of "Set as default table style for this document" > Clikc Format > Set the border line color > Click double OK.

[image]

[image]

Then if you create a table, it would apply the new style, including the border color.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that default line color cannot be changed, this does give me another option.